# What is the asymptotic bound of linear code used for?

Tags: asymptotics, coding-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I am studying coding theory recently. There is a notion "asymptotic bound" of linear code, like "Asymptotic Singleton Bound". It gives a rate when a relative distance is approached to parameter $\delta$
and the length of code is infinite, where the rate is defined as $k/n$ and the relative distance is defined as $d/n$. (Refer to the book "Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes" written by W. Cary Huffman and V.Pless.)

However, I don't know what is the point for this notion, e.g, what is it used for? If $n$ is infinite and relative distance is approached to $\delta$, is it means that the distance $d$ also increase as $n$, for example, suppose $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$, $n \rightarrow 2n $, then $d \rightarrow 2d$?

Comment: did my answer resolve your query?

Answer (score 1):

Errors usually hit each bit/symbol independently. Therefore if each bit is in error with probability $p$ which is less than the rate $\delta$ the errors can be detected. If $p$ is less than $\delta/2,$ they can be corrected.

If $p>\delta$ then no reliable transmission is possible. Letting $n$ get large is to allow the sample error statistics behave by the law of large numbers, when the number of actual errors is with high likelihood near $p n.$

Comment: Here is my understanding. If $\frac{d}{n}$ approaches to $\delta$, then the correct ability is $(\delta n-1)/2$. When $n$ is infinite, the number of actual errors is roughly $pn$. Thus if $p < \frac{\delta}{2}$, the code can handle the errors.
The asymptotic bound is to tell us the rate $\frac{k}{n}$ whatever the relation $p$ and $\delta$ is? What else information can we obtain from the asymptotic bound? Thank you!